# Use 3rd party pod in sub-project (framework project)

Tags: ios, cocoapods, alamofire, ios-frameworks

I am using XCode 8 + Swift 3.

I created a fresh iOS project named "**MyApp**".

Then, I create a Cocoa touch **framework** project, named "MySubProject". 
(The idea is to have **MyApp** project accessing **MySubProject** code.)

They are on the same level folder:

```
- MyApp/
- MySubProject/
```

I added **MySubProject** into **MyApp** project, linked the **MySubProject** framework. Everything works fine. My project structure looks like this:

[image]

All works until here! (MyApp code can access MyService code)

Now, I need **MySubProject** to use Alamofire to communicate with backend. So, under `MySubProject/` I setup the Alamofire with CocoaPod, which creates the `MySubProject.xcworkspace`.

I think I need to remove the previous `MySubProject.xcodeproj` and using `MySubProject.xcworkspace`, so I deleted the reference of `MySubProject.xcodeproj`& add the `MySubProject.xcworkspace` to `MyApp`, it then looks like this:

[image]

As you can see, I can not see the source code of **MySubProject** now.

What is the correct way to use Alamofire or any 3rd party library through CocoaPod in Framework sub-project?

===== UPDATE ======
I need to add Alamofire into `MySubProject`, not `MyApp`. I followed instruction in Alamofire offical website to manually add Alamofire to `MySubProject`, the project structure then looks like this:

```
- MyApp
  - MySubProject.xcodeproj
    -Alamofire.xcodeproj
```

After that, I can access Alamofire in MySubProject, no compile error. However, when I run my app in emulator, I got runtime error:

```
Referenced from: /Users/myname/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/MyApp-hezjlyvzxnavccenabxdepgftbrg/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/Alamofire.framework/Alamofire
  Reason: image not found
```

How to solve that?

Comment: Take a look at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45319504/is-this-the-correct-way-to-create-dynamic-embedded-framework-with-embedded-cocoa

Answer (score 1, accepted):

<strike>You can do this three different ways.</strike>

1) Add the dependency directly to you MyApp project

2) Build the MySubProject and add the library with the dependency in it to the MyApp project. (assuming the MySubProject will be a library)

3) When using custom pods you can provide a dependency in the .podspec file. Via this method I can import my own library (as a pods) which depends on other Cocoapods.

EDIT: After a good look we came to the conclusion that the methods above didn't met leem.fin's specific requirements. It's NOT possible to include a framework into another framework. But there're two other options:

1) Ship the secondary framework besides your framework and link it to your own framework. This way both MySubProject and MyApp can link to that framework.

2) Import the sources directly into MySubProject so they'll be compiled with the MySubProject.framework and they're accessible for other targets that simply link to MySubProject.

The easiest way is importing the sources directly into the MySubProject. If you don't copy the resources but link to the folder, you can git update the sources when you need to to get the latest changes.

Comment: I need to add Alamofire into `MySubProject`, not `MyApp`.

Comment: Why can't you add it to MySubProject and compile that to a library with the AFNetworking as a dependency? I think you're overcomplicating your project.

Comment: I can't because I tried and it can't. Please see my other question about that here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45307258/using-3rd-party-framework-alamofire-in-my-sub-project-cocoatouch-framework

Comment: You need to rethink your structure of your project and understand how dependencies work. I have the same structure but I added Alomfire as a pod to my project and then I include the MySubProject in MyApp. When I open MyApp I need to add the Pods_MySubProject.framework to my linked frameworks and it works.

Comment: Because I want to deliver the MySubProject framework to other developers to use, they only need to access my API which has Alamofire returned backend data directly.

Comment: Have you looked into the possibility to link the product of Alomfire? I think you can link the library from Alomfire.xcodeproj in the MyApp project by linking the framework (as I suggest in my previous comment).

Comment: That's exactly why I point you to the other thread which you are complaining I point you back and forth. In that thread, I showed what I tried to link Alamofire to MySubProject, but it is not working. In that thread I am asking why it is not working. I showed the error I got in xcode.

Comment: Did you add the Alomfire.framework as an Embedded Framework?

Comment: In framework project, there is no such option "Embedded Framework", if it has that, I wouldn't have problem. You can try in xcode, create New project --> Cocoatouch Framework. That is MySubProject.

Comment: You cannot embed a framework in a framework so your project setup is incorrect. So you need to ship Alomfire separate from your MySubProject (which is a framework as well). To make this easy for myself I use pods which creates MySubProject.framework and Alomfire.framework and "ships" them together.

Comment: So you need to add both MySubProject and Alomfire to the MyApp project and then link them there.

Comment: OK, that makes sense. But how could I use Alamofire in MySubProject? My main idea behind this is to have backend communication logic in MySubProject, do you mean it can't be done?

Comment: Well.... Yes you can but it might not be the sexiest way of doing it. Copy the Alomfire sources directly into your MySubProject as if it where your own and call them. This way they'll be compiled with you API. I got the following situation working (http://imgur.com/a/jOlB1).