# Using 3rd party framework (Alamofire) in my sub-project (CocoaTouch framework)

Tags: ios, xcode, xcode8, alamofire, ios-frameworks

I am using XCode 8 + Swift 3.

I created a fresh iOS project named "**MyApp**".

Then, I create a Cocoa touch **framework** project, named "MySubProject". 
(The idea is to have **MyApp** project accessing **MySubProject** code.)

I added **MySubProject** into **MyApp** project, linked the **MySubProject** framework.

In XCode project navigator it looks like this:

```
MyApp
  > MySubProject.xcodeproj
```

Everything works fine. Code in `MyApp` can access code in `MySubProject`.

Now, I need to add **Alamofire** into `MySubProject`. I followed instruction in [Alamofire offical website](https://github.com/Alamofire/Alamofire) to **manually** add Alamofire to `MySubProject`, the project structure then looks like this:

```
MyApp
  > MySubProject.xcodeproj
     > Alamofire.xcodeproj
```

So, `MySubProject` has dependency on **Alamofire** framework. This is what it looke like under `MySubProject` target--> General :

[image]

After that, I can access Alamofire in `MySubProject` code, no compile error. MyApp is Built successfully. However, when I run my app in emulator, I got **run-time error:**

```
dyld: Library not loaded: @rpath/libswiftSwiftOnoneSupport.dylib
Referenced from: /Users/myname/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/MyApp-hezjlyvzxnavccenabxdepgftbrg/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator
```

/Alamofire.framework/Alamofire
      Reason: image not found

Why? & How to solve that?

Comment: Have you tried building the Pods scheme yet?

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem here with installation of cocoapods to use alamofire. A solutionthat did work for me was download Alamofire from github, then I compiled the framework of alamofire with xcode and used it in my app. When I put alamofire in my work area I got an error so I had to put alamo xcode project into there too. This way it works for me.

Answer (score -1):

If you want to use alamofire, there's a better way to install it. You can use the cocoapods for intall 3rd party frameworks. So, you must follow these steps:

1.- Please install cocoapods by gems `sudo gem install cocoapods`

2.- Go to your folder by terminal and type `pod init`, then type `vim Podfile`

3.- You can see a file that you can add your 3rd party frameworks so you must add Alamofire to your target and write it from your vim `:wq`. For example type this:

```
# Uncomment the next line to define a global platform for your project
# platform :ios, '9.0'

target 'YourTarget' do
use_frameworks!

pod 'Alamofire', '~>4.0'
```

4.- Now you must to type `pod install` from your terminal and that's it. Open your `xcworkspace` generated from cocoapods and type `cmd + B` from xCode. Then after that you can import Alamofire to your classes.

Comment: I know that, but this installation way doesn't fit my need. Please see my  question about that here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45281648/use-3rd-party-pod-in-sub-project-framework-project

Comment: Alfredo: He's referring us to each other so I think he's just overcomplicating the situation and doesn't know what he actually wants.

Comment: @Leon, I am very clear about what I want, I just don't know a proper way to make it happen. I post two questions because they are two different questions on the same project. You don't really understand my question doesn't mean I don't know what I want.

Comment: I want my framework project embed Alamofire, and the framwork project can be used by my app project with Alamofire capability. In my question, I showed what I tried but not working. Like I said, I am very clear what I want.

Comment: @Leem.fin - Did u got the solution for your question? I am also in same situation. I want to add "Alamofire" in my custom framwork and getting same error. I am using Alamofire.framework which I generate through carthage. If I don't add this it works fine with only Swift classes but getting this error as soon as I add Alamofire.framwork and generate my custom framwork and use it in my test project. _Please reply back if you have got solution for this problem._