# How to use dynamic framework inside the pod?

Tags: ios, xcode, dynamic, frameworks, cocoapods

I have a free framework (**FW**). It distributes via cocoapods. In this framework i use another framework. It compiled as dynamic framework (**DFW**).

So in my FW i need to write `import DFW` and after this can use it. Also the DFW is linked in *Embedded Binaries* and *Linked Frameworks and Libraries* in my project target.

After that i push my FW to cocoapods and after installing it tells `Cannot find such a module` near the `import DFW` statement.

The question is - *how to properly distribute cocoapod with embedded dynamic frameworks in it*?

Comment: Hi how did you fix this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no way to use dynamic frameworks in cocoapods, because it brings in a versioning issues. Instead of this use `s.dependency` in the `podspec` file. You can read [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45319504/is-this-the-correct-way-to-create-dynamic-embedded-framework-with-embedded-cocoa) also.