# Xcode/Cocoapods: I can't access a dependency that's in a framework linked to my project

Tags: ios, frameworks, cocoapods

I want to embed several projects and frameworks in only one workspace.

Here is the structure in Xcode:

[image]

`Project1` and `Project2` are application projects, and `BaseFramework` is a Cocoa Touch framework.

Now what I want to do is to add a pod dependency to the framework, then link this framework to one of the projects and access the dependency in this project. Here is what I tried with my Podfile:

```
platform :ios, '12.1'
use_frameworks!
inhibit_all_warnings!

workspace 'BaseWorkspace'

def shared_pods
  pod 'Toast-Swift'
end

project 'Project1/Project1.xcodeproj'
project 'Project2/Project2.xcodeproj'
project 'BaseFramework/BaseFramework.xcodeproj'

target 'BaseFramework' do
   project 'BaseFramework/BaseFramework.xcodeproj'
   shared_pods
end
```

Then, I linked the framework to `Project2` :

[image]

Everything compiles fine, I can import `BaseFramework` in `Project2`... but I'm unable to use methods from `Toast-Swift`. What am I doing wrong here?

Thanks for your help.

Comment: I'm not sure why would you want to access a dependency through a framework as intermediate layer and not directly. I think you should use access `Toast-Swift` directly from `Project1` / `Project2` instead of trying to access it through `BaseFramework => Toast-Swift`. Can you please elaborate it further?

Comment: Well, I thought about it that way : let's suppose I want to create a base framework that reuses code from a dependency, and then several projects should include that framework, without necessarily use elements from the framework's dependency. Is this a bad approach?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

By declaring project targets inside framework target scope, project targets will get all dependencies of framework

```rb
platform :ios, '12.1'
use_frameworks!
inhibit_all_warnings!

workspace 'BaseWorkspace'

def shared_pods
  pod 'Toast-Swift'
end

target 'BaseFramework' do
   project 'BaseFramework/BaseFramework.xcodeproj'
   shared_pods

   target 'Project1' do
      project 'Project1/Project1.xcodeproj'
   end

   target 'Project1' do
      project 'Project2/Project2.xcodeproj'
   end
end
```

Answer (score 0):

It would be ideal to create a ***pod*** for your framework and add 'Toast-Swift' as a ***dependency*** as its ideal to avoid umbrella frameworks.Refer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45319504/is-this-the-correct-way-to-create-dynamic-embedded-framework-with-embedded-cocoa)

Comment: That's what I was thinking first, but since I'm planning to use this framework only in my team, I thought it could be a better idea to use a local framework instead. Guess I will have to use a private pod if I follow your idea, right?

Comment: yes,you could distribite your framework as a private pod.

Comment: Ok thank you. I'll wait to see if any other answer comes and if not I'll accept yours. I'm a bit surprised and disappointed though that there is no easy solution to do what I want...