# dyld: Library not loaded: @rpath/RxSwift.framework/RxSwift

Tags: swift, frameworks

I created a custom framework that uses RxSwift, RxCocoa and others third-party frameworks. The custom framework compile correctly but when I added to the application it crash with this error :

```
dyld: Library not loaded: @rpath/RxSwift.framework/RxSwift
  Referenced from: /private/var/containers/Bundle/Application/49800223-0217-4591-A8D1-
```

I tried to use module map to expose the third-party but without success :(
Any help please because I didn't found a solution since two days and I'm blocked.
Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to copy framework dependencies to application. Process depends on way you add dependencies in framework.

For CocoaPods you can check my answer here: [Xcode/Cocoapods: I can't access a dependency that's in a framework linked to my project](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55164377/xcode-cocoapods-i-cant-access-a-dependency-thats-in-a-framework-linked-to-my/55320104#55320104)